# Is P(A . B') = P(A) . P(B')?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Is this identity $ P(A. B^c) = P(A).P(B^c)$ correct?

My attempt to prove this is as follows:

$$ RHS = P(A). P(B^c) \\
= P(A) . (1 - P(B)) \\
=P(A) - P(A).P(B) \\
=P(A) - P(A \cap B)\\
=P(A \cap B^c) \\
=LHS
$$

Also, can this be extended as such:
$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = P(A^c) . P(B^c)$ ?

My attempt to prove:

$$ P((A \cup B)^c) = P(A^c). P(B^c) \\
= P((A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)) \cup P((B^c \cap A) \cup (B^c \cap A^c)) \\
=P(A^c \cap B^c) \\
$$

Are these identities correct? I'd also appreciate any help on the proofs.

Comment: No, the identity is not correct in general.  Recall that $\Pr(X\cap Y)=\Pr(X)\Pr(Y)$ is true **if and only if**  $X$ and $Y$ are independent events.

Comment: For $A$ and $B$ independent, yes, $\Pr(A\cap B^c)$ will equal $\Pr(A)\Pr(B^c)$ and it can be shown as you did.

Comment: Yes, assuming that A and B are independent events. That’s really really important. The fact that you haven’t mentioned this at all makes me worry that you have deeply misunderstood something

Comment: As for your proof of the second half... that was highly unnecessary.  Just call $B^c$ something else... like $C$, from which you are asking if $\Pr(A^c\cap C)=\Pr(A^c)\Pr(C)$ which follows immediately from the earlier proof.

Comment: What are the premises (if any) regarding the events' independence?

Answer (score 3):

Only valid for independent events. So itself the identity is wrong without explaination of independency of evenrs.